# How to add additional track in twilio-video?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, twilio, twilio-video

After updating twilio-video JS SDK (from 1.x to 2.x) I have a problem in adding additional device. 
This is example error message - ERROR TypeError: transceiver.sender.replaceTrack(...).then(...).finally is not a function.
If I disable this device i get new error message - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The [LocalVideoTrack #5: 8da6e8e0-a9c1-473b-9916-484a17f61524] was unpublished.
And if I repeat enable device - is OK.
Below is example publishing track in share additional track method.

```
        this.room
        .localParticipant
        .publishTrack(this.deviceTracks[type]);
        this.deviceTrackShared[type] = true;
```

Below is example unpublishing track -

```
        this.room
        .localParticipant
        .unpublishTrack(this.deviceTracks[type]);
        this.deviceTrackShared[type] = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this issue. I lost a lot of time searching for errors in the code, but I just needed to update zone.js from 0.8.x to 0.9.x. Now it's working fine!